# ToDo List with Google Keep?

Tags: software-recommendation

I run the Widget from Google Keep on my Android phone and I'm quite happy with that.

Now i want some app/program for that for my Ubuntu Unity Desktop. Is there something with google keep sync.?

Answer (score 2):

Right now there are no software packages that can sync Google Keep directly to your Ubuntu desktop.

However, since you can easily sync Google Keep with Google Drive, you can access all your notes by going to https://drive.google.com/keep/ in a web browser on your Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 2):

or check out this, which works fine with the stock chromium from Ubuntu-Software-Center for me:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/add-google-keep-to-unity

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! While this theoretically answers the question, it's better to summarize or include key parts of the information from the link here.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu eX00r! It is usually not a good idea to only post a link in an answer. You should at least explain what the link instructs you to do, or (a much better approach is to) post the actual steps and screenshots from that link. This is to benefit people from the future should the link die.

Comment: You can go to the chrome web store and integrate [Google Keep](http://goo.gl/f6nWXo). Its automatically integrated in the Unity Dash. PS: I wanted to comment on ex00r's answer but I don't have enough reputation so answered separately.