# Is it possible to use a program (non-Chrome) with Google Keep / Notes?

Tags: google

I'd like to see and try if I can find any program that could be synced with Google Keep / Notes (actually it is only reachable under its old name: `keep.google.com`).

This program shall **not** be Chrome/Chromium please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/280995/todo-list-with-google-keep

Comment: Is anyone aware of a command-line implementation that allows to add new notes from the Bash command-line terminal?

Answer (score 1):

At this time there is no Ubuntu software that addresses this issue. Google Keep does have a app that can be used on Ubuntu, but you have to get it through Google Chrome.

Go to the [Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-google-keep-in-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/) site and follow the instructions. Unfortunately this does require Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it is. http://keep.google.com works on Firefox.

Also, you can consider Andrey Polischuk's Electron application called [`keep`](https://github.com/andrepolischuk/keep):

```
sudo apt install npm
git clone https://github.com/andrepolischuk/keep
cd keep
npm install
```